# android surfaceview crashes on resize

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, segmentation-fault

I am using a slightly custom SurfaceView (CSV) for drawing something on it in a separate thread. My CSV is inside a LinearLayout among some other controls. I hide all these other controls setting their visibility to GONE and it caused my CSV to occupy all the space.

So, my app sometimes (quite rare) crashes during resizing CSV (caused by toggling visibility of UI, if it matters). It crashes on Nexus 7 (2013) with messages like "fatal signal 11 (sigsegv) at 76812000 (code=1) thread 10456" and never crashes on my XperiaZ.

To draw I use a separate thread based on a runnable that performs a tick (code comes later) and sleeps. The thread is started in surfaceCreated and is killed in surfaceDestroyed. I tried to restart the thread in surfaceChanged, but it has no effect.

```
   public void run() {
        while (!is_stopped){
            TickImpl();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }

   private void TickImpl() {
        Canvas canvas = null;   
        try {

            canvas = surface_holder.lockCanvas();

            synchronized (surface_holder) { 
                if (canvas != null){
                    canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                    scene.RenderTo(canvas); // Here I do draw
                }
            }      
        } finally {
            if(canvas != null) {
                surface_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
     }
```

Sorry, if something is described not well enough, I am a junior developer. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

```
10-24 14:27:16.403: A/libc(17724): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x75cdb000 (code=1), thread 17740 (Thread-513)
10-24 14:27:16.503: I/DEBUG(176): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-24 14:27:16.503: I/DEBUG(176): Build fingerprint: 'google/razor/flo:4.3/JSS15R/804956:user/release-keys'
10-24 14:27:16.503: I/DEBUG(176): Revision: '0'
10-24 14:27:16.503: I/DEBUG(176): pid: 17724, tid: 17740, name: Thread-513  >>> com.example.dice <<<
10-24 14:27:16.503: I/DEBUG(176): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 75cdb000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     r0 75cdb000  r1 ffffffff  r2 000008e0  r3 40412014
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     r4 75cda800  r5 000000ab  r6 00000900  r7 000008e0
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     r8 0000ffff  r9 74555afc  sl 40285bcc  fp 74555c84
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     ip 00000001  sp 74555914  lr 40285bf4  pc 402568d8  cpsr 20070010
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d0  ffffffffffffffff  d1  ffffffffffffffff
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d2  ffffffffffffffff  d3  ffffffffffffffff
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d4  0000047000000000  d5  0000022544094000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d6  0000000044094000  d7  4140000044096000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d8  3f800000433d5555  d9  3f800000433d5555
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d10 00000000433d5555  d11 0000000000000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d16 4028000000000000  d17 4029000000000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d18 bfe4471a00000000  d19 40624ef56abf9160
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d22 3fe4471a00000000  d23 3fe8c14be0000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 4067aaaaa0000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 c05dfe81127b4400
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d28 405dfe81127b4400  d29 40624ef56abf9160
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     d30 4067aaaaa0000000  d31 0000000000000000
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     scr 20000012
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176): backtrace:
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     #00  pc 000678d8  /system/lib/libskia.so
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     #01  pc 00096bf0  /system/lib/libskia.so
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     #02  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176): stack:
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558d4  400fc605  /system/lib/libbinder.so
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558d8  4010d064  /system/lib/libbinder.so
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558dc  40104373  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::ProcessState::self()+94)
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558e0  70a219d0  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558e4  745558fc  [stack:17740]
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558e8  74555a78  [stack:17740]
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558ec  400fbab9  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::sp<android::IBinder::DeathRecipient>::~sp()+22)
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558f0  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558f4  4010253f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::releaseObjects()+44)
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558f8  74555a78  [stack:17740]
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          745558fc  70a2c960  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555900  00000050  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555904  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555908  df0027ad  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          7455590c  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555910  74555940  [stack:17740]
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     #00  74555914  75cda800  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          ........  ........
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     #01  74555914  75cda800  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555918  00000001  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     #02  7455591c  40288504  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDraw::drawPaint(SkPaint const&) const+420)
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555920  00000080  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555924  000005d4  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555928  00000080  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          7455592c  00000001  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555930  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555934  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555938  00000470  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          7455593c  00000225  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555940  752aa3a8  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555944  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555948  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          7455594c  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555950  00000470  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555954  00000225  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):          74555958  00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r0:
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdafe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdaff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb0a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb0b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb0c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cdb0d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r3:
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40411ff4 40068a24 400a0184 40069818 40412000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412004 00000194 ff7fffff ff7fffff ff7fffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412014 40256850 40256970 403ea7ec 403ea7fc  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412024 403ea800 403ea804 403ea808 403ea810  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412034 403ea814 403ea81c 00000080 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412044 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412054 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412064 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412074 00000000 00000000 403eb1d0 403eb1d4  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412084 403eb1d8 403eb1e0 403eb1e4 403eb1e8  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     40412094 00000080 00000000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     404120a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     404120b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     404120c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     404120d4 01010101 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     404120e4 ffffffff 00000006 00000001 05050707  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r4:
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda7e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda7f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda800 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda810 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda820 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda830 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda840 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda850 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda860 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda870 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda880 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda890 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda8a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda8b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda8c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     75cda8d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r8:
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0000ffdc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0000ffec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0000fffc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001000c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001001c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001002c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001003c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001004c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001005c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001006c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001007c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001008c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     0001009c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     000100ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     000100bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     000100cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r9:
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555adc 7529d5b8 00000001 74455f60 4007b1f4  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555aec 4027ce00 00000470 7529d668 74555b40  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555afc 7527d650 7529d640 752aa3a8 752aa3a8  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b0c 7529d5c0 7527d648 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b1c 7529d5b8 00000000 00000000 3f800001  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b2c 433d5555 3f800000 7529d668 00000001  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b3c 74555be8 7529d5b8 81200005 752aa238  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b4c 4f200009 401bb5f8 752aa240 81200005  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b5c 40040a13 40078000 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b6c 4f200009 401bb5f8 4003d9c1 40564cd8  
10-24 14:27:16.603: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b7c 00000000 74555bd4 00000000 7527b708  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b8c 74555bac 4f200009 00000000 00000001  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555b9c 402c73d8 00000000 403dfe30 40414608  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555bac 00000001 74455f68 74555c70 403dfe30  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555bbc 70a4bcc8 00000001 402922d0 00000008  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555bcc 00000470 7529d5b8 74555c10 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176): memory near sl:
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bac e1a0200c e08f3003 e793300e e593c000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bbc e12fff3c e8bd8008 0018c158 fffff7d4  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bcc e92d4008 e1a0c0a1 e59f301c e6ff1072  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bdc e59fe018 e1a0200c e08f3003 e793300e  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bec e593c000 e12fff3c e8bd8008 0018c124  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bfc fffff7d0 e5903004 e5901000 e1b00081  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c0c e3a0c08e e04c0c20 e1a0c401 e38cc102  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c1c e1a0003c 22600000 e1b01083 e3a0c08e  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c2c e04c1c21 e1a0c403 e38cc102 e1a0113c  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c3c 22611000 e8820003 e12fff1e e591c00c  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c4c e92d0030 e5914008 e5903004 e5901000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c5c e1b00081 e3a0508e e0450c20 e1a05401  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c6c e3855102 e1a00035 22600000 e1b01083  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c7c e3a0508e e0451c21 e1a05403 e3855102  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c8c e1a01135 22611000 e04030c4 e041c0cc  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c9c e8821008 e8bd0030 e12fff1e e591c00c  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176): memory near fp:
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555c64 74451530 00000000 40876c50 74455f60  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555c74 00000001 00000008 417aa9a0 43480000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555c84 408a6ed3 74455f60 6f16d6e5 40181ad9  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555c94 74451540 00000033 4007b1f4 1ec00001  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555ca4 00000000 00000000 4007b1f4 74451558  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555cb4 ffffbfff 74451558 408cbc3d 74451530  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555cc4 7527f6f0 00000000 00000c80 0000fa00  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555cd4 4006af4c 00000032 00000000 000003e8  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555ce4 00000032 00000000 000003e8 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555cf4 74555d58 278282af 00000032 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555d04 400698cc 744518c0 00000001 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555d14 744518c0 ffffffd4 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555d24 4003e6b8 00000000 98942b6c 744518d0  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555d34 744518c0 00000000 74451530 74812ff8  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555d44 98942b6c 98942b6c 4204d8e4 4204d8e0  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555d54 74451530 0000000b 00000058 1dcd64ff  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176): memory near sp:
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     745558f4 4010253f 74555a78 70a2c960 00000050  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555904 00000000 df0027ad 00000000 74555940  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555914 75cda800 00000001 40288504 00000080  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555924 000005d4 00000080 00000001 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555934 00000000 00000470 00000225 752aa3a8  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555944 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000470  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555954 00000225 00000000 74555a98 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555964 400b7905 00000000 400b7577 74555a98  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555974 00000000 00000001 400b796b 00000001  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555984 74555a78 00000001 74555a78 745559b8  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     74555994 40561ded 74555a44 745559b7 74555a78  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     745559a4 405620f7 745559b7 00000000 00000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     745559b4 752a98b8 7529d5b0 40564e9c 752a98b8  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     745559c4 7529d5b8 752a9594 40040a13 40078000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     745559d4 00000000 00000000 40564e9c 752a98b8  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     745559e4 4003d9c1 40564cd8 400b49b9 74555a98  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176): code around pc:
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     402568b8 ba00001c f2201110 e3520040 ba000012  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     402568c8 f2202150 e3520080 ba000008 e1a0c3a2  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     402568d8 f40002cd f40002cd f40002cd f40002cd  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     402568e8 e25cc001 1afffff9 e212207f 0a000018  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     402568f8 e1b0c2a2 0a000004 e25cc001 f40002cd  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256908 1afffffc e212201f 0a000011 e1b0c222  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256918 0a000004 e25cc001 f4000a8d 1afffffc  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256928 e212200f 0a00000a e3520008 ba000001  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256938 e2522008 f400078d e3520004 ba000001  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256948 e2522004 e4801004 e3520000 da000000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256958 e0c010b2 e49d0004 e12fff1e e320f000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256968 e320f000 e320f000 e3520001 04801004  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256978 012fff1e e3520004 ca000005 e3520000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256988 012fff1e e4801004 e2522001 1afffffc  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40256998 e12fff1e e3520010 ba000035 eea01b10  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     402569a8 f2202150 e3520020 ba00002c e3520040  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176): code around lr:
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bd4 e59f301c e6ff1072 e59fe018 e1a0200c  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285be4 e08f3003 e793300e e593c000 e12fff3c  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285bf4 e8bd8008 0018c124 fffff7d0 e5903004  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c04 e5901000 e1b00081 e3a0c08e e04c0c20  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c14 e1a0c401 e38cc102 e1a0003c 22600000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c24 e1b01083 e3a0c08e e04c1c21 e1a0c403  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c34 e38cc102 e1a0113c 22611000 e8820003  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c44 e12fff1e e591c00c e92d0030 e5914008  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c54 e5903004 e5901000 e1b00081 e3a0508e  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c64 e0450c20 e1a05401 e3855102 e1a00035  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c74 22600000 e1b01083 e3a0508e e0451c21  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c84 e1a05403 e3855102 e1a01135 22611000  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285c94 e04030c4 e041c0cc e8821008 e8bd0030  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285ca4 e12fff1e e591c00c e92d0030 e5914008  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285cb4 e5903004 e5901000 e1b00081 e3a0508e  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     40285cc4 e0450c20 e1a05401 e3855102 e1a00035  
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176): memory map around fault addr 75cdb000:
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     75bf6000-75c07000 rw- /dev/kgsl-3d0
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     (no map for address)
10-24 14:27:16.613: I/DEBUG(176):     75e91000-75e92000 --- 
10-24 14:27:16.744: I/BootReceiver(511): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
10-24 14:27:16.754: I/ActivityManager(511): Process com.example.dice (pid 17724) has died.
```

Comment: can u show me error log when application get crashed?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the position of synchronization code

```
synchronized (surface_holder) { 
    try {

                canvas = surface_holder.lockCanvas();

            //    synchronized (surface_holder) { 
                    if (canvas != null){
                        canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        scene.RenderTo(canvas); // Here I do draw
                    }
             //   }      
            } finally {
                if(canvas != null) {
                    surface_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
                }
    }
```

Comment: This does not change the behavior: app still crashes unpredictably and rarely on Nexus 7(2013) and never crashes on XperiaZ.

Comment: No all drawing now is in this thread. I'll try to do that to test the behavior. But still I'll have to draw in a separate thread as I need a quite big frame rate.